# Why won't this take the stuff for color and use it to decide the colors?

Tags: java, recursion, colors

//im trying to get this to take the method I created for color so that It could create different shades of red

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Pop {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
    StdDraw.enableDoubleBuffering();
    java.util.Scanner scan = new java.util.Scanner(new java.io.FileReader("numfile.txt"));
    int a = scan.nextInt();
    int b = scan.nextInt();
    int c = scan.nextInt();

    //asks user for input to choose colors
    Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 10");
    int number = myObj.nextInt();  // Read user input
    System.out.println("The number you selected is " + number + ". Good choice! One moment...");
    //creates new variables by multiplying the input number and file numbers


        StdDraw.enableDoubleBuffering();
        rerectangle(0.0, 0.5);
        color(a*number);
        StdDraw.show();
    }

static void rerectangle(double x, double radius) {
    if (radius > 0.01) {
        StdDraw.setPenColor(color(), 0, 0);
        StdDraw.filledRectangle(0.5, radius, radius, radius);
        rerectangle(x + radius * 0.2, radius * 0.9);
    }
}

static int color(int color1) {
    return (color1 * 2);
}
```

}

Comment: `color(a*number);` - what do you think this is doing?  **and** what is `color()` ?

Comment: color(a*number); is supposed to multiply what i have in the text file times what the user puts in and then it would put that into the color method I have at the very bottom. then it would multiply that by two and put it into where red is supposed to be defined in the STD.Draw

Comment: `color()` does not look like it would compile as it needs an `int` argument.  Further `int` arguments are immutable, that is why there is a return value.  You are not using this return value.

Comment: You need to assign this `color(a*number);` to a variable, for example `int newShade = color(a*number);` then when you need to pass that value to the rectangle method `rerectangle(0.0, 0.5, newShade);` and update the method to accept another input `rerectangle(double x, double radius, int redShade)` thin use that on this line `StdDraw.setPenColor(redShade, 0, 0);`